# BitBucket Pipeline only On-Demand

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a pipeline for one of my repositories and it automatically deploys every time I commit and push any code - is there a way to make it so it only runs the pipeline when I wan to execute it, instead of automatically running whenever I push new code?

Comment: This kind of thing I build into my git workflow via branching and tagging. Do a bunch of changes in one branch, merge to another when you're ready to trigger the pipeline build, deployments on tags.

Comment: I couldn't even find out how to have a pipeline only for a specific branch

Comment: It's out there. Here is an [example](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/branch-workflows-856697482.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer in comment above by @sytech: [pipelines](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/branch-workflows-856697482.html)